# Steam Problem on closing or reopening

Tags: games, freeze, reboot

I cannot re-open Steam on Ubuntu after having closed Steam. In order to effectively run or use steam again I seem to have to restart my whole computer, which is a chore. Also, Steam (especially during or after Universe Sandbox) likes to freeze frequently - which requires me to close steam to clear the freeze.

I usually use terminal to killall steam, sometimes it creeps along fast enough to click the x graphical button to close it, this is my preferred method. But sometimes I am forced to use terminal or the task bar to close the windows.

No matter by what method it is closed, I usually cannot reopen Steam after that unless I totally restart the machine. Clicking steam again might get the "steam is updating" window, once, but after that nothing happens.

Something of Steam appears to be running in the background, but not fully coming into the forefront to use. After I try clicking it any number of times, it may respond again to killall steam which will kill whatever is there.

Attempting to start Steam by simply typing "steam" in terminal gives this:

```
steam.sh[169693]: Running Steam on Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
steam.sh[169693]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[169763]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[169693]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
```

But nothing happens. If I try to run steam again it will produce the same result. But, if I killall steam AGAIN from this point, it says this:

```
steam.sh[170117]: Running Steam on Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
steam.sh[170117]: STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
setup.sh[170187]: Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
steam.sh[170117]: Steam client's requirements are satisfied
[2022-03-30 05:43:43] Startup - updater built Mar 28 2022 16:05:10
[2022-03-30 05:43:43] Opted in to client beta 'publicbeta' via beta file
You are in the 'publicbeta' client beta.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1648513529)
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

From this, the terminal never completes or concludes the result so you would have to close the terminal to do something else.

How can I restart steam or close it cleanly, so that if I reopen it some time later it will work fine without requiring a total restart of the machine?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the version that's installed from the repository. It doesn't work very well for reason and I had problems with it failing to close games and leave them running the background. I only noticed it later when I just happened to see them in `htop` or whatever and noticed all the missing memory.

My recommendation is uninstall the Ubuntu included steam completely, get the official .deb file from [the steam repo](https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/) and follow the instructions. I wouldn't be surprised if all your problems immediately vanished after that. Mine did. :D